# select all columns in mysql table but do not show duplicate results, SELECT DISTINCT id

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

i am trying to select * the columns in my table and pull these through using mysql query, i am getting a duplicate result with one row, so i am wanting to NOT show duplicate results from mysql. i am trying to do this using SELECT DISTINCT 'id'

in theory this should not pull trough the row a second time / as a duplicate result then because i am telling it to select each id only once.

this is not working though and i am still getting a duplicate result, please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

```
$data3 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT id, company_name, company_reg_number, date   
 FROM supplier_session WHERE status != 'Failed'
 ORDER BY date ASC") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data3 )) { 
 $days = $row['date'];
 $when = $days*0; 
 $str = $row['date'];
 $str2 = substr($str, 0); // "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
 if ($when <= 31){
 echo "<tr><td style=\"width:100px;\"><p>".$row['id'] . "</p></td>"; 
 echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><p>".$row['company_name'] . "</p></td>"; 
 echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><p>".$row['company_reg_number'] . "</p></td>";
 echo "<td>"; echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row['date'])); echo "</td>";
 if ($days >= 8) {
 echo "<td style=\"width:200px;\"><p>";
 print ($str2 -7);
 echo " days overdue</td>";      
 }
 elseif ($when <= 7){
 echo "<td style=\"width:200px;\"><p>Completed {$str2} days ago</td>";
 }}
 $q2 = "SELECT DISTINCT id, company_name, company_reg_number, date FROM supplier_session WHERE status != 'Failed' " or die (mysql_error());
 $result2 = mysql_query($q2);
 $count2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);
 echo "<td>";
 echo "Pending</td>";
 echo "<tr>";
 }
```

My table looks like:

```
id  |  session_number  |  user_IP  |  date  |  company_reg_number  |  company_name |  form1_completed  |  form2_completed  |  form3_completed  |  form4_completed  |  completed_date  |  status
```

Comment: Could you please include the duplicate result in your question?

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions and learn to indent your codes.

Comment: Please add table data and required O/P with tried query

Comment: If `id` is auto incrementing, then `select distinct id, xxx ...` is pointless (id will never have dupes). Shouldn't you select a distinct be on a column that can have duplicate values?

Comment: id is auto increment, but if i select distinct company_name instead then how will i do this because if i change id to company_name it still doesnt stop duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark here but, try group by the ID ?

```
SELECT id, company_name, company_reg_number, date   
FROM supplier_session WHERE status != 'Failed' GROUP BY id
```